# VS2017 15.7.3 is no longer hitting breakpoints Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Xamarin.Forms app using VS2017 (Windows) and since I've upgraded to 15.7.3 I am no longer able to hit breakpoints.  Instead, anytime there is a breakpoint to be hit I see the following:

[image: VS2017 15.7.3 pause until thread returns]

It doesn't matter where I put a break point, the debugger never stops there.  I've even tried `Debugger.Break();` and I get the same results.

I've had no issues debugging Xamarin.Forms apps before this upgrade.

I realize this is probably due to threading, but I can't find any options that would have changed.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried the [procedure suggested at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224100/8093394)? It used to works for such issues.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoRafaelSouza, I just tried that solution, and it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Did you use xamarin profiler? It can be cause this.

Comment: No I don't use the profiler

Comment: Try checking the "Debugging information" option: Select the project Properties > Build > Advanced > Output > Debugging information. Try setting this value to Full. See [Advanced Build Settings Dialog Box (C#) Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/advanced-build-settings-dialog-box-csharp#output)

Comment: @Mark Erickson, Could you debug this app in other VS machine? Whether all apps have the same issue or just the specific one? Would you please share the latest information about this issue in your side?

Comment: @Benl All projects in the solution have debug info set to FULL.

Comment: @Jack Zhai-MSFT I am able to debug other Xamarin.Forms apps without issue.  The only difference between my other Xamarin.Forms apps and this one is that I am using .NET standard libraries and not PCL libraries.  The build configuration has all project building in Debug configuration.

Comment: Also, I completely removed VS2017 15.7.3, rebooted, re-installed 15.7.3, got a fresh copy of the code, rebuilt the app, tried to debug, and had the same issue.  This didn't happen until I upgraded to 15.7.3, so I may try to downgrade to 15.7.2 and see if that removes the issue.

Comment: Please also check project Properties > iOS Debug > Debugging & Instrumentation > Enable Debugging. See troubleshooting FAQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/debugger-settings).

Comment: Yes, Enable Debugging was already enabled.

Comment: So I uninstalled 15.7.3, and re-installed 15.6.x and the debugging is working fine now.  I did try uninstalling and re-installing 15.7.3 and the issue remained.  Not definitive by any means, but it seems like there may be an issue with 15.7.3.

Comment: @Mark Erickson, Do you also edit the .xxproj file in your side? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350048/debugging-referencing-net-standard-1-4-libraries-in-xamarin-forms-android-app and https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2712

Comment: @Mark Erickson, What about this issue? Do you get any latest information in your side?

Comment: I uninstalled 15.7.3 and installed 15.6.1 and debugging is working as it should.  But now I'm back to the IDE becoming unresponsive after 5 or so debug runs. Very frustrating, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

- Clean your project
- Exit Visual Studio
- Delete the .vs folder
- Delete /bin and /obj in your shared project and all native ones
- if you are compiling for iOS, also reboot your build host (Mac)
- if you are compiling for iOS, also make sure that Visual Studio and XCode have been upgraded to the latest version as well
- Restart Visual Studio (wait for the connection to your mac to be established)
- Rebuild your Shared Code manually
- Then rebuild your native projects

If you are using nuGet packages, make sure that they are up to date as well, especially the Xamarin.Forms package. Also it can happen, that some dependencies end up twice (or even more often) in your .csproj files. Make sure to clean them up, though you have to edit them manually (always remember to keep a backup!) and make sure that the latest libraries are being used.

In rare cases it can help to restart your Windows machine and repeat the procedure above after the reboot.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the steps above, but the issue still remains.  I am noticing it seems to be random.  I can debug once, breakpoints are hit, no code change, debug again, and it's back to the original issue.  I'm going to re-install the IDE see if that shakes anything loose.